# How to read data from Excel which is open and getting updated every seconds using C# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, interop

I am using Office.Interop.Excel to read data from Excel using C# ASP.Net & Dotnet 6.
I can read the Data and everything seems to be working fine.

But I have a challenge here.
The excel which I am reading data from would be updated every second.
But I am seeing an error while trying to open it and update random data.
The error says that the file is locked for editing.

Please have a look at the code below:

```
public double GetGoldPrice()
{
   string filename = @"D:\Test.xlsx";
   int row = 1;
   int column = 1;
   Application excelApplication = new Application();
   Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(filename);
   string workbookName = excelWorkBook.Name;
   int worksheetcount = excelWorkBook.Worksheets.Count;
    
   if (worksheetcount > 0)
   {
      Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)excelWorkBook.Worksheets[1];
      string firstworksheetname = worksheet.Name;
      var data = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range) worksheet.Cells[row, column]).Value;
      excelApplication.Quit();
      return data;
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine("No worksheets available");
      excelApplication.Quit();
      return 0;
    }
}
```

My end goal is to get live data from Excel whenever I fire the function.
The Excel would be open and can be editing any time.

Please help!

Comment: I am not able to recreate the problem. Using your code, I can read from an Excel file while also writing to it in a loop every second from another process. Maybe the file you are using was not closed out properly and it is locked. What happens if you start with a new file?

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks for the comment, it worked with new file. The main problem I have with interop is that it only reads the data which is saved. But the data would be updated every second and it should reflect same asap. So if the data is updated every second, we wont be in position to save it everytime. So how should we overcome this issue. Please help

Comment: I don't think it will work unless the workbook is saved after each change. If you can move the workbook to SharePoint then I think you could probably make something work but I can't be specific about how

Comment: You can try enabling the [sharing in the excel file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-the-shared-workbook-feature-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534). So your changes (via appliation) and other users will be updated simultaneously. You may get alert dialog boxes (like changes are updated by other users ...) while saving which you need to handle. Without sharing two process/users cannot update the excel file at the same time.

Comment: if you do not want to update and just want to read it then you can open the excel file as readonly. You can pass the readOnly param as true in Workbooks.Open method.

Comment: Your design here is flawed - Office Interop isn't designed to be used on a server, where ASP.NET Core would normally run. It's generally not licensed for that, nor is it good at being used from multiple threads like you'd expect an ASP.NET Core app to do.  See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2).

Comment: Instead, it might make sense to write an add-in for Excel that clients can run on their machines (or perhaps use a macro) that is capable of communicating back to your ASP.NET Core app on the fly.

Comment: @mason Can you suggest how can I create a macro which sends data back to ASP.NET app

Comment: Go write one. Go research macros and add-ons, such as Visual Studio Tools for Office.. Make at attempt. If you get stuck, make a new question and clearly explain what you tried. I'm not just going to write a macro from scratch that does your job for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said your file is xlsx so you would be better not using Interop but Open XML SDK 2.5. Then you can open the file in read only mode:

```
 using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = 
        SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
    {
        // Code removed here.
    }
```

Check here to get familiar with [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-parse-and-read-a-large-spreadsheet)

Comment: I agree that Open XML would be preferable but you can still open it read only with interop.

Comment: It looks like Interop has some other considerations that I do not know.

Comment: The main problem I have with interop is that it only reads the data which is saved. But the data would be updated every second and it should reflect same asap. So if the data is updated every second, we wont be in position to save it everytime. So how should we overcome this issue. Please help

Comment: How the excel data is getting updated every second?

Comment: Its getting updated through a external script.

Comment: Open XML SDK link is dead. I am getting a 404, page not found error. Appreciate if the updated link is placed